# VBA - Returning an array of strings from a function, array elements are blanked out

Tags: arrays, excel, function, vba

I'm working on a kind of smart checklist application using Excel 2010 because I am a masochist.

I'm attempting to return an array of strings from a function; when I examine it in the debugger, the returned array has the expected number of elements, but the contents are blank.  I need someone to tell me what I'm doing wrong.

I'm declaring a set of arrays of strings at the module level (in the creatively named `Module1`) like so:

```
Private BuildTestGroup(0 To 3) As String
Private CodingStandardsGroup(0 To 16) As String
Private ConfigFilesGroup(0 To 2) As String
Private TestingGroup(0 To 1) As String
Private DeploymentGroup(0 To 0) As String
```

They are initialized when the worksheet is loaded with the following function in the same module:

```
Sub InitNameGroups()

  BuildTestGroup(0) = "CleanSource"
  BuildTestGroup(1) = "ApplyPatch"
  BuildTestGroup(2) = "BuildPatch"
  BuildTestGroup(3) = "VerifyBuild"

  CodingStandardsGroup(0) = "InputCheck"
  CodingStandardsGroup(1) = "InitializeCheck"
  ...
End Sub
```

Called from here:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
  Call Module1.InitNameGroups
  Call Module1.SetCalledFromSource(False)
End Sub
```

In response to a click event on a checkbox in the worksheet, one of the arrays will be retrieved:

```
Sub CleanSource_Yes_Click()
  '
  ' Only execute this code in response to an event on the worksheet;
  ' do not execute if called from another function like UpdateGroup
  '
  If Module1.CalledFromSource = False Then  
    Dim Names() As String
    '
    ' Get the names of all button groups for the BuildTest section
    '                           
    Names = Module1.GetNames("BuildTest")
    '
    ' check Yes box, uncheck No and NA
    '
    Call Module1.UpdateGroup("CleanSource", "Yes") 
    '
    ' if all Yes checkboxes in BuildTest
    ' group have been set, set group
    ' label to Complete
    '
    Call Module1.CheckStatus("BuildTest", Names)   
  End If                                           
End Sub
```

using the following function, again from `Module1`:

```
Function GetNames(GroupName As String) As Variant
  If GroupName = "BuildTest" Then
    GetNames = BuildTestGroup
  ElseIf GroupName = "CodingStandards" Then
    GetNames = CodingStandardsGroup
  ElseIf GroupName = "ConfigFiles" Then
    GetNames = ConfigFilesGroup
  ElseIf GroupName = "Testing" Then
    GetNames = TestingGroup
  Else
    GetNames = DeploymentGroup
  End If
End Function
```

The issue is that when I examine the `Names` array in the `CleanSource_Yes_Click` function, it has the expected *number* of elements, but all of the elements are blank (causing the `CheckStatus` function to fail with a runtime error).  This is happening for *all* my checkbox handlers, and *all* attempts to retrieve one of the name arrays give me the same result.

My question is, why are the elements coming back blank?  Am I not declaring the `Names` array properly in the click handler, or am I not declaring the `GetNames` function to return an array properly?

This scheme worked once upon a time, but I've obviously tried to do something clever and wound up breaking it.  I just don't know what.

---

**Solved**

It turns out that the `Workbook_Open` and `Worksheet_Activate` functions weren't being triggered properly because of how I'm working on this; if I flip worksheets, the arrays get initialized properly and everything works *just fine*.

Answer (score 0):

I'm taking one shot: have you forgotten to call `InitNameGroups` anywhere before the mighty `click`?

Comment: Missed! now let me reproduce the issue

Comment: Never mind, found the problem; `Workbook_Open` and `Worksheet_Activate` weren't being triggered properly.

Comment: I'm glad you found it. Like I wasn't wrong after all ;-)